# Why can't an acer aspire XC-703 turn on without his hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, acer-aspire, efi

I received an [Acer Aspire XC-703](http://www.acer.it/ac/it/IT/content/model/DT.SX0ET.008) and i tried to sobstitute the included 500GB hard drive with a 32GB SSD. But the pc won't even turn on (power led off, cpu fan stuck at max rpm, no video output) when it's own hard drive is disconnected.

Is this some kind of weird security system, is it known? Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Ok, this is getting weirder and wirder. Apparently it works if the HD is not connected to the SATA, but it has to be connected to the PSU

Comment: If you wish to add further information to the question, please do so by **[edit]ing** the question and adding the relevant information. Don't bother with "edit" headings; the full edit history is available to anyone who might be interested. Instead focus on working the additional information into the question where it makes the most sense.